# Separate limit_req_status per zone - nginx throttling

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, throttling, rate-limiting

I'm testing nginx rate limiting [example](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/). The directive `limit_req_status` can return a custom error message for requests that exceed the zone's rate limit. I've defined 2 zones (limit1 & limit2).

**Is it possible to return a different error message for each zone ?**

This is what I have currently

```
location /login/ {
    limit_req zone=limit1 burst=20 nodelay;
    limit_req zone=limit2 burst=10;

    limit_req_status 444;
}
```

This is what I want

```
location /login/ {
    limit_req zone=limit1 burst=20 nodelay;
    limit_req zone=limit2 burst=10;

    limit_req_status 444; # if limit1 is breached
    limit_req_status 4xx; # if limit2 is breached
}
```